# Does the equation still satisfy, for $n\to\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Aspiring mathematician here.

I played around with some established formulas and got the following equation where $n$ is any positive integer.
$$
\frac
{\displaystyle \sum_{A=1}^\infty \frac{\prod_{B=1}^n e^{\frac{1}{2B}}}{A^2\prod_{C=1}^n e^{\frac{1}{2C-1}}}}
{\displaystyle \prod_{D=2n+1}^\infty e^{\frac{(-1)^{D+1}}{D}}}
=\frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$
I wanted to know if the form still satisfies $\pi$ squared divided by $12$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Where does this convoluted equation come from? If it is derived from "established formulas", then its validity entirely depends on what manipulations you performed to create it.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle

Answer (score 0):

n doesn't matter.
That formula just combines
$ln 2 = \sum (-1)^{n+1}/n$
with
$\sum 1/m^2 = \pi^2/6$.